# Sample from a distribution and plot in python

Tags: sampling, importance-sampling, particle-filter

I am trying to understand Particle Filter and Importance Sampling Principle from a [UniFreiburg Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYIjB93oAUo) and [this USNA  document](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/crabbe/SI475/current/particleFilter/particleFilter.pdf) on particle filters.

Simultaneously, I am also trying to write a document about what I understood. I want to create such a plot that can visualize the samples generated from a distribution.
[image: Samples Generated from a distribution]

Firstly, generating samples from a distribution and plotting itself seems to be a task. I use `numpy.random.normal()` to generate 5000 samples from a distribution. But when I plot the sorted values, I get a plot like this.
[image: sorted-samples]

How do I generate samples for this purpose and be able to plot them as shown in the first plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and welcome to CV.

I suggest trying something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

n = 500  # sample size
mu = 0  # mean
sigma = 1  # sd

a = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,n)
sns.distplot(a, hist=False, kde=True, rug=True)
```

It looks that you were plotting the sorted values against their index, while what you want to do is a plot of the distribution, so either a histogram or a distplot via kde (Kernel Density Estimation).
Since seaborn already contains this, it is the quickest way. `rug` will also draw the position of your elements on the x axis. It's not with red dots as in your plot, but close enough. Otherwise you can do so manually via matplotlib, but it's definitely longer and more verbose.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for giving me a direction. I am still a bit confused with how this function generates the y-axis probabilities, and how I can do more. But I am trying out a few things and will get back if I cannot understand. Thanks once again.

Comment: To be clear - y axis values are not sampled. You only sample value on the X axis, and you use their position to have an estimation of the probability of the underlying distribution (y-axis). It's kind of like doing a histogram - in a histogram you show the number of points falling in every given region (with a given width). With kde you are usually assigning a probability instead, centered on each point that you sample. See details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

Comment: thank you very much, not only for the answer, but also for extra material that i could read up on. This thread was very helpful. I was unaware of these topics.